# Position on UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation, uiimageview

Me again. I have a simple question. I have an UIImageView like the one shown below.
[alt text http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/1999/volumen.png](http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/1999/volumen.png)

That UIimageView is supposed to be the knob to control the volume of my iphone project. My question is, how to know the positions of bar on the UIImageView when it is rotated? Because the volume needs to be 0.5 when the little bar on the cercle is vertical.

I got a piece of code which is (in the touchMoved method):

```
float dx = locationT.x  - imgVVolume.center.x;
float dy = locationT.y  - imgVVolume.center.y;


CGFloat angleDif = 0.0f;

movedRotationAngle = atan2(dy,dx);

if (beganRotationAngle == 0.0) {
    beganRotationAngle = movedRotationAngle;
    initialTransform = imgVVolume.transform;
}
else {
    angleDif = beganRotationAngle - movedRotationAngle;
    CGAffineTransform newTrans = CGAffineTransformRotate(initialTransform, -angleDif);
    imgVVolume.transform = newTrans;
}
```

Help please.

Comment: whats wrong? what is the question?

Comment: The question is how to know the position of the imageview so as to adjust the volume

Comment: wouldnt that be the angleDif you are looking for? Possibly you have to add them all together :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what input mechanism you want to use to control the rotation.

If the knob is to rotate based on a single finger touch dragging from side to side then you can create a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and attach it to the knob `UIImageView`. The `translationInView:` method returns a `CGPoint` which is the amount of X and Y movement from the touch-down point. You can feed that into a formula like the one you post to get an angle of rotation. You'll want to keep track of delta from last position and also check for stop limits (like 0..360) to prevent over-rotation.

OTOH, if you're going to use two finger rotation then you'll want to use a `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` and look for the `rotation` value. Just feed that into a `CGAffineTransformRotate` and set it to the `UIImageView` transform. That takes care of all of the above for you. Again, you'll want to check for stop limits.

Comment: could you please provide an example? It's a single finger touch I confirm :D